# Corona Mobile App Storage Solutions

Tags: database, sqlite, lua, coronasdk

I am currently developing a mobile app using the Corona SDK and Lua. I need to store information about each user and load the information for the current user when they load the app. What is the best method to store this information for each user, and how would I get this data on app load. I was thinking about using sqlLite and having a single row for each user. However when the user re loads the app I would have no way of accessing the data for the current user because when the app loads I would need something to index the database. Is there any way I can get some information from the mobile device on app load to index the database? Any ideas or suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not clear on where the database is stored.
If it's remote on a server just use the device ID

system.getInfo( "deviceID")

If it's local and you have multiple local users then use a login.
You could use a registration process for either instance and store
The registration keys for automatic access when launching the app.

Comment: I could use the system.getInfo("deviceID") for local as well, which I think is the better approach.

Answer (score 0):

take a look at amazon's services.
like S3,simpleDB, dynamoDB..

Some implementations are already available in Code Exchange

http://developer.anscamobile.com/code/amazon-simpledb-api
http://developer.anscamobile.com/code/amazon-s3-rest-api-implementation-corona